# Dart language support async/await programming style, or similar?

Tags: dart, dart-async

It is possible write similar code in Dart language?

```dart
int i;
try {
  i = await getResultAsync();
} catch(exception) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/using-future-based-apis/

Comment: I believe the only languages currently supporting `async` are C#/VB/F#. C++ has something similar proposed. Dart/JS will probably be a bit slower to adopt because CPS is common and less onerous (they are by nature functional languages).

Comment: Typescript language similar to Dart language (has JS output) and it propose (not implemented yet) async/await. Time will tell.

Comment: @StephenCleary Scala also has it https://github.com/scala/async

Answer (score 3):

Basic support is already available.
See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/ for more details.

```dart
main() async {
  print(await foo());
  try {
    print(await fooThrows());
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

foo() async => 42;

fooThrows() async => throw 'Anything';
```

Answer (score 2):

Not for now. See issue [Support for "await" in Dart](http://dartbug.com/104).