# Async/Await feature in Dart 1.8

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Is it in the 1.8 release as an experimental feature like enum or is it not? And how can I use it in the Dart Editor? Is there a nice article or example app that can get me started with this?

When it is still an experimental feature what is recommended for pub packages? Is it fine to use that feature in pub packages or not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27195775/217408

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update 2**

The most recent nightly build also supports `async*`

```dart
void main() {
  generate().listen((i) => print(i));
}

Stream<int> generate () async* {
  int i = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    yield ++i;
  }
}
```

**Update**

`yield` and `yield*` in a method marked `sync*` (returning an Iterable) are already supported in `1.9.0-edge.43534`

```dart
void main() {
  var x = concat([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
  // x is an Iterable which iterates over the values 1 to 9
  print(x);
}

// A method marked `sync*` returns an `Iterable`
concat(Iterable left, Iterable right) sync* {
  yield* left;
  yield* right;
}
```

```dart
void main() {
  print(filter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (x) => x.isEven));
}

filter(ss, p) sync* {
  for (var s in ss) {
    if (p(s)) yield s;
  }
}
```

`async*` generator functions (returning a Stream) are not yet supported.

**Original**

Basic support is already available.
See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/ for more details.

```dart
main() async {

  // await
  print(await foo());
  try {
    print(await fooThrows());
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }

  // await for
  var stream = new Stream.fromIterable([1,2,3,4,5]); 
  await for (var e in stream) { 
    print(e); 
  }
}

foo() async => 42;

fooThrows() async => throw 'Anything';
```