# How to listen for a change of variable (class getter)?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I want to ask for help in simple construct.

Simply: I have a class `MyClass{}`, which simply creates a dialog containing custom title, custom message and ok/cancel buttons called `okButton` and `cancelButton` (also getters/setters in that class).
I have a function `bool myFunction()` outside the class, which creates a new instance of the class (using its default constructor) to show dialog to user.
Finally I want (according to the button clicked by user) to return true or false in my function.

My idea how it could work (not working; preview of my ideal algorithm):

```dart
// Define a class
class MyClass {

  // Define buttons
  ButtonElement okButton;
  ButtonElement cancelButton;

  // Define a constructor
  MyClass(){
    // Create a dialog, define buttons
  }
}

// Define bool function
bool myFunction(){
  // Create a new instance of class
  MyClass myNewClass=new MyClass();

  // Return bool value after user clicked on some button
  myNewClass.okButton.onClick.then => true;
  myNewClass.cancelButton.onClick.then => false;
}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You must not add `return` for fat arrow functions `=>`

Comment: It is not a code, just algorithm. I just want to return true in the bool function if the user clicked ok in the dialog created by that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async' show Future, Completer;

class MyClass {

  // Define buttons
  ButtonElement okButton = new ButtonElement()..text = 'OK';
  ButtonElement cancelButton = new ButtonElement()..text = 'Cancel';

  // Define a constructor
  MyClass(){
    // Create a dialog, define buttons
  }
}

void main() async {
  var dialogResult = await myFunction();
}

// Define bool function
Future<bool> myFunction() {
  Completer c = new Completer();
  // Create a new instance of class
  MyClass myNewClass=new MyClass();

  // Return bool value after user clicked on some button
  myNewClass.okButton.onClick.first.then((e) => c.complete(true));
  myNewClass.cancelButton.onClick.first.then((e) => c.complete(false));

  return c.future;
}
```

You should enable the experimental `async` feature in DartEditor preferences. See also [Async/Await feature in Dart 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212220)

Comment: This is executed asynchronuously. You can't do something like `var ok = myNewClass.okButton....`. What's actually happening is, when the button is clicked the code passed to `listen` or `then()` is executed. At this point `myFunction()` has already been finished a while ago.

Comment: I see. You can use the new `async`/`await` feature. I'll update the answer to show how you can accomplish this.

Comment: Well, too much complicated and with parameter to the `main()` function (I write a package, so I have not got the access to the `main()` function) :/ I tried to set another `.then()` after the first one and it just worked. It looks like a better solution to my last little question. Many thanks for your help. And finally, I don't use DartEditor, but could I ask if I need to specify to the command line when running pub build, that I'm using `await`?

Comment: I used `main()` only as an example to show how to call the function. I don't think you can make this less complicated. The call and execution of `myFunction` and the click to a button are at totally different times. `myFunction` has finished long before a user can click a button. `Future` is the only thing that allows to make the function appear like it's finishing on button click. The completer is used to complete the `Future` on the first of 'several' events.

Comment: Is it still so much complicated or did anything change after new async features had been released in SDK v1.9?

Comment: I changed the answer to use async/await already back in December. Nothing has changed since then and probably won't in the foreseeable future.