# Using --enable-async with pub

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm using the new async/await syntax in my code, and everything is working great if I run my application  directly from dart using something like `C:\dart\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --enable_async --checked C:\code\dart-app\main.dart`

When I try to run `pub run main.dart` on the same application, however, I get an error message `error: line XX pos XX: use flag --enable-async to enable async/await features`. The `--enable-async` flag seems to be something for Dart itself, so I can't add it to the pub command.  How can I build my application using pub in a way that allows me to us the async/await syntax?

Comment: As of Dart 1.9 (in dev channel at the time of this writing), you should have access to async/await without requiring a flag or a transformer.

Comment: Note pub uses "checked mode" ([#22049](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22049)); this can raise  exceptions you won't see otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pub run` command loads and executes the transformers registered in your pubspec.yaml file, before executing the app. So you can use the async-await transformer to handle async/await instructions. See [Async/Await feature in Dart 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212220/async-await-feature-in-dart-1-8)

Comment: It seems that this is the correct/only way to do it right now. Unfortunately, the transformer doesn't work if you are also using Enums right now. Such is the cost of living on the edge I suppose.