# How do I change my simple asynchronous Dart function to use the new async keyword?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have a Dart function that looks like:

```dart
Future beAwesome() {
  if (notActuallySupported) {
    return new Future.error(new UnsupportedError('uh oh'));
  }

  return new Future.value(42);
}

// ...

beAwesome().then((answer) => print(answer));
```

I want to use the new [async/await](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/await-async/) functionality. How do I change my function?

Answer (score 3):

In general, add the word `async` after your function's signature and before the `{`. Also, return raw values instead of wrapping those values in futures. Also, throw actual exceptions instead of wrapping the errors with a future.

Here's the new version:

```dart
Future beAwesome() async {
  if (notActuallySupported) {
    throw new UnsupportedError('uh oh');
  }

  return 42;
}

// ...

var answer = await beAwesome();
print(answer);
```

Note that you should still use `Future` as the return-type annotation.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212220/async-await-feature-in-dart-1-8