# Channel primitive in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

Is there a `channel` primitive in Dart as there is in Go for example? The closest I found is [StreamIterator](https://api.dartlang.org/133557/dart-async/StreamIterator-class.html).

The use case would be to allow a consumer to asynchronously process values one by one. Additionally, if there is no value, it should just wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with streams

```
import 'dart:async' show Stream, StreamController;

main() {
  StreamController<int> sc = new StreamController<int>();

  sc.stream.listen((e) => print(e));

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sc.add(i);
  }
}
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/34d1e081f2281f02bb17)

See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/streams/
- https://www.dartlang.org/articles/creating-streams/

You can't "just wait" in Dart, especially in the browser.

There are also `async*` generator functions available in Dart to create streams. See for example [Async/Await feature in Dart 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212220/async-await-feature-in-dart-1-8/27212791#27212791)

A "naive" translation form `await for(var event in someStream)`

```
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  StreamController<int> sc = new StreamController<int>();

  startProcessing(sc.stream);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sc.add(i);
  }
}

Future startProcessing(Stream stream) async {
  StreamSubscription subscr;
  subscr = stream.listen((value) {
    subscr.pause();
    new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((_) {
      print('Processed $value');
      subscr.resume();
    });
  });
  //await for(int value in stream) {
  //  await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((_) {
  //    print('Processed $value');
  //  });
  //} 
}
```

The actual implementation takes a different approach

> The way the await-for loop is implemented uses a one-event buffer (to avoid repeatedly pausing and resuming).

See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24956#issuecomment-157328619

Comment: 'await for' works for this, was not clear from the documentation that one could just await inside the for body and that the stream values would be buffered. DartPad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/470e2e2429c3c065f5e5

Willing to accept your answer if you edit it to include only processing one value at a time.

Comment: Sure, `await for` is nicer syntax but otherwise it's the same.

Comment: If it's the same, how would you achieve it without using 'await for' syntax? The crucial part, is that the next value is not processed before the previous one is done being processed (which might happen asynchronously)

Comment: See https://dartpad.dartlang.org/4608ce4ab271445fc30d. `await` just makes code look like sync code. It's still executed async. Everything you can do using `await` you can do without. The Dart VM converts `await` to it's async equivalent on-the-fly.

Comment: @Codespawner - it seems you are primarily concerned with ensuring the events are processed in order, and processing of event n completes before processing of event n+1 starts. Dart is single threaded so these conditions are guaranteed.

Comment: Not if you execute async calls within the event handler. While for example  waiting for a response from a server, it would start processing the next event.